# thread performance on Linux vs. Solaris

Tags: linux, performance, multithreading, solaris, pthreads

This Linux Magazine article http://www.linux-mag.com/id/792 explains the difference in the way threads are implemented in Linux as compared to commercial Unixs such as Solaris. In summary, Linux uses a 1-to-1 mapping of user threads to kernel threads, while Solaris uses a many to many mapping. The article implies that this might give Solaris a performance edge, especially when switching between threads. Before I spend the time to test this, has anyone already done it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

People used to think that M:N threading was a good idea, but everyone has been moving to 1:1 threading; it has lower overheads and works better in an SMP environment. Solaris moved from M:N threading to 1:1 threading in [Solaris 9](https://web.archive.org/web/20090305012246/http://www.sun.com/software/whitepapers/solaris9/multithread.pdf), I believe. That article you linked to seems to be from 2001, so it's a bit outdated (it's subscriber only, so I couldn't read it).

Comment: bugmenot.com is you friend for sites like linux-mag.com

Comment: I am not a subscriber to Linux Magazine, and I was able to see the article. Thanks for the Solaris 9 information. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @bobmcn I edited my answer and linked to a whitepaper on Solaris 9 threading, that mentions that MxN scheduling is gone and replaced with 1:1 threading.

Comment: This [Princeton article on Solaris process scheduling](http://www.princeton.edu/~unix/Solaris/troubleshoot/schedule.html) says the single-level model was introduced in Solaris 8 and made the default in Solaris 9.  Note, though, that it is only the *default* -- an application can make use of the more sophisticated model simply by linking with a different library.  It seems quite reasonable to make the easier route the default, but perhaps the more sophisticated model offers better performance for highly concurrent applications. (?)

Comment: @AmigoNico Concurrency and performance (as well as correctness and ease of programming) is a very complex topic, that I can't do justice to in the comment section here. It's possible that there are specialized applications in which M:N scheduling is useful, and there are a variety of thread-pool libraries and languages which implement their threads over pools of hardware threads to allow you to do that. My point is that it seems that for most purposes, 1:1 is actually preferable to M:N, hence Solaris moving to 1:1 by default.