# Compile Java to behave like GO code

Tags: java, multithreading, compiler-construction, go

Would it be possible to write a Java compiler or Virtual Machine that would let you compile legacy java application that use thread and blocking system call the same way GO program are compiled.

Thus new Thread().run(); would create light weight thread and all blocking system call will instead be asynchronous Operating System call and make the light weight thread yield.

If not, what is the main reason this would be impossible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James Henstridge has already provided good background on Java green threads, and the efficiency problems introduced by exposing native OS threads to the programmer because their use is expensive.

There have been several university attempts to recover from this situation. Two such are [**JCSP**](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/jcsp/) from Kent and **CTJ** (albeit probably defunct) from Twente. Both offer easy design of concurrency in the Go style (based on Hoare's CSP). But both suffer from the poor JVM performance of coding in this way because JVM threads are expensive.

If performance is not critical, CSP is a superior way to achieve a concurrent design because it avoids the complexities of asynchronous programming. You can use JCSP in production code - I do.

There were reports that the JCSP team also had an experimental JNI-add-on to the JVM to modify the thread semantics to be much more efficient, but I've never seen that in action.

Fortunately for Go you can "have your cake and eat it". You get CSP-based *happen-before* simplicity, plus top performance. Yay!

Aside: an [interesting Oxford University paper](http://wotug.org/paperdb/show_pap.php?f=1&num=687) reported on a continuation-passing style modification for concurrent Scala programs that allows CSP to be used on the JVM. I'm hoping for further news on this at the CPA2014 conference in Oxford this August (forgive the plug!).

Answer (score 6):

Earlier versions of Sun's Java runtime on Solaris (and other UNIX systems) made use of a user space threading system known as "[green threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads)".  As described in the [Java 1.1 for Solaris documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3461/6jck06gqk/index.html#ch2mt-41):

> Implementations of the many-to-one model (many user threads to one kernel thread) allow the application to create any number of threads that can execute concurrently. In a many-to-one (user-level threads) implementation, all threads activity is restricted to user space. Additionally, only one thread at a time can access the kernel, so only one schedulable entity is known to the operating system. As a result, this multithreading model provides limited concurrency and does not exploit multiprocessors. The initial implementation of Java threads on the Solaris system was many-to-one, as shown in the following figure.

This was replaced fairly early on by the use of the operating system's threading support.  In the case of Solaris [prior to Solaris 9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/811729/721283), this was an M:N "many to many" system similar to Go, where the threading library schedules a number of program threads over a smaller number of kernel-level threads.  On systems like Linux and newer versions of Solaris that use a 1:1 system where user threads correspond directly with kernel-level threads, this is not the case.

I don't think there has been any serious plans to move the Sun/Oracle JVM away from using the native threading libraries since that time.  As history shows, it certainly would be possible for a JVM to use such a model, but it doesn't seem to have been considered a direction worth pursuing.

Comment: This is different because when compiling using Java green threads it was still possible for you code to call blocking system call and thus block all the green thread for doing any processing. I was more thinking of a model where code look like it's blocking but doesn't really block.

Comment: Well, that's basically what the M:N threading library on older versions of Solaris did: if one program thread made a blocking call, another program thread would be scheduled to run on that kernel thread.